# iPhoneX: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer not occupying the entire screen?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have made a custom camera in a UIViewController but I am not able to preview the camera output to the entire screen on the iPhoneX.  There appears to be a substantial padding between the camera view and the edge of the screen.  My view seems to have been even inset from the safe area for sure.  Please can anyone advise?

iPhoneXs Max:
[image]

my code:

```
class CaptureImageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate  {


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        startAVCaptureSession()
    }


func startAVCaptureSession() {
    print("START CAPTURE SESSION!!")

    // Setting Up a Capture Session
    self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    // Configure input
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

    guard
        let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: videoDevice!) as AVCaptureInput,
        self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)else {return}

    self.captureSession.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

    // Capture video output
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.init()
    guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {return}
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.init(label: "videoQueue"))
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)


    // start
    self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    self.captureSession.startRunning()


    // Display camera preview
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: self.captureSession)

    // Use 'insertSublayer' to enable button to be viewable
    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    previewFrame = previewLayer.frame


}




}
```

My layout:

[image]

[image]

Comment: just set constraints with respect to super view not safe area

Comment: @SPatel Please could you elaborate as i only have one view and that is anchored to the window

Comment: try -> previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `previewLayer.frame = view.frame` to

```
let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
previewLayer.frame = frame
previewFrame = previewLayer.frame
```

Comment: that didn't work.  strangely, on the iphone 7 plus, by code works as desired - but not on the iphon xs

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: unfortunately that did not work either.  i think there is something overlooked when working with iphone xs display.

Comment: @dean there is something to do with AVCaptureSession.Preset or AVCaptureDevice.Format as the capturesession starts with different aspectRatio and the device has different aspectRatio that is why in notch devices the camera is not in full screen. I'm also facing the same issue and searching for answers. Did you got any solution for this.
Thanks